# To create price rule, price_rules.json is not working

Tags: shopify-api, node-fetch

I am trying to create a price rule with Shopify admin API.
https://{storename}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/price_rules.json

I used postman and node-fetch.
But when I call the API, it returns array and doesn't create any price rule.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?